# Can you name a project "she's"?

Tags: abbreviations, titles

One of my friends photography project is named "she's". I personally believe the name is wrong and that it sounds better and looks better if he uses "she is".

Is it grammatically correct to use "she's?

Thank you

Comment: A name is a name. You can name anyone or anything whatever you like, without adherence to any convention; in fact, for artistic projects, the artist may choose a name that is deliberately unconventional. So there is nothing wrong with naming a photography project *she's*; a name does not have grammar; and whether something else would sound or look better is really a matter of opinion.

Comment: Good comment, but if it was not an artistic project, if you had to enforce grammar, will it be correct?

Comment: Without context I'm afraid we'd just be guessing.  Does the project owner mean to imply that it is a collection of images of females?  In that case, "She's" doesn't mean "she is", but rather, plural of "she".  A single word, with no context cannot be determined to be grammatical or not.

Comment: It doesn't sound like this is your project; if your associate chooses to name it FR3D does our opinion really matter?

Comment: As the name of an art project there's nothing wrong with it.  The name of an art installation or something similar is essentially a proper noun, and is not subject to having its "innards" dissected grammatically.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Yes it's a fashion collection shoot. @ElliottFrisch we are deciding the name. He does not speak English and he only wants the apostrophe because he thinks it will appeal to English speaking clients

Comment: Seems more like a greengrocer's apostrophe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are fine, but have strongly different subtexts.

With-apostrophe, "**She's**" is appealing because it has ambiguity: could mean "*she is*"; or "*she has*" (in the sense "she did", or "she owned", or...?); could mean a plurality of *she*'s under the same exception rule as "do's and don'ts" in order to prevent misreading; could, with a little typographical play, be shés; could mean belonging to someone called *She*; could be posessive and so synonymous with "*Her*". This ambiguity, and the fact that it's not a complete statement or sentence, makes it an intriguing name, which implies the unsaid part of the sentence, makes the mind grope for the rest of it, and by this omission, implies a sense of style. This, in turn, implies that the work will be a similarly ambiguous and subtle study of what it means to be a woman.

"**She is**" on the other hand, is a bold, flat and definitive statement, a grammatically complete and self-contained sentence, which has a completely different appeal. It implies that the art will be similarly bold and "in your face", and likely strongly feminist: it suggests a celebration of a woman's existence, and possibly by extension, of women's existence in general.

Comment: Note that the original question lists the name as "she's", in all lower-case.  This is perfectly acceptable as an "artsy" proper name -- "proper" capitalization "rules" need not be followed.